# SQL datepart mmm yy not sorted in chronological order

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, sql-order-by

I am not able to sort the mmm yy summary using date part coz I wanted month year format

Got the output as below

```
Col1   Col2
AA     Apr 19
BB     Feb 20
CC     Dec 19 
DD     May 19
EE     Jan 20
```

How to sort this month year wise

Expected result

```
Col1   Col2
AA     Apr 19 
DD     May 19
CC     Dec 19
EE     Jan 20
BB     Feb 20
```

Comment: Tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Specify the expected result.

Comment: Add DD. MAY 19 too.

Comment: Is your data stored as separate month abbreviation and (two-digit!) year columns; or is the result of a query that has converted an actual date to those values already, which would probably make the sort much simpler? An [mcve] would be helpful, including the right data types for the raw data you're working from.

Comment: It's a query that converts date to mmm yy format ...

Comment: OK, so why not order by the original date? If you're aggregating, say, daily data by month then that's still easy to do. It would be helpful to show a simple version of your query though, so we can see what you're really doing.

Comment: Is that really the output order you get now? What are you ordering by, `col1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use `to_date()` for this:

```
select col1, col2
fro mytable 
order by to_date(col2, 'mon yy')
```

Note that Oracle interprets the month name according to NLS parameters, such as `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`. So for this to work, your database's language must be American.

If that's not the case, you can try and force the parameter as a third argument to `to_date()`:

```
to_date(col2, 'mon yy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American')
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
order by year, 
         (case month when 'Jan' then 1 when 'Feb' then 2 . . . end)
```

There may be simpler ways to express this, depending on your database.

Answer (score 1):

> It's a query that converts date to mmm yy format

As you are working with months, you are presumably aggregating daily data by month, and are currently doing something like:

```
select count(*) as col1,
  to_char(your_column, 'Mon RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as col2
from your_table
group by to_char(your_column, 'Mon RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
order by col2;
```

which orders the data by the string representation of the date. (That isn't exactly what you show in your sample, but not sure if you just created that oddly...)

If you aggregate using the actual month instead, by truncating the date values (giving the first day of that month), then you can group by and order by that truncated date; and just convert to a string at the last moment for display only:

```
select count(*) as col1,
  to_char(trunc(your_column, 'MM'), 'Mon RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as col2
from your_table
group by trunc(your_column, 'MM')
order by trunc(your_column, 'MM');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=484a8f08f61629e8dd16d3d2639ef16e)

Like @GMB, I've specified the language to use for the month abbreviations.